# WScript.Sleep() ~ WSScript is undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, jscript

I'm trying to follow some example code from microsofts mdn site..

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("calc");

while (oExec.Status == 0)
{
     WScript.Sleep(100);
}

WScript.Echo(oExec.Status);
```

I'm currently writing a javascript/JScript to run a few batch commands. Everything works fine if I don't use WScript.Sleep(). However, If i try to use it, to prevent locking up the browser, i'm getting an error that WScript is not defined.

I figured that I needed to define it myself. However, I have been searching mdn website all day with no luck. This is my first time using any "windows only" products I could be coompletly overlooking something.

If you want to see the documentation I'm looking through it is located here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.85).aspx

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Freddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WScript` is an object that is defined when the Javascript is run within the Windows Script Host, aka WSH.  The object is not available within the Javascript engine in a web browser.

If you are really trying to produce "batch like" files, then you don't need a browser, and I'd say you probably don't want a browser. You can write your code into a .js file and just run it from the cmd.exe prompt or Explorer window with a double-click.

Answer (score -2):

Change the script language from JavaScript to JScript